# How to log correlation id with Sequelize?

Tags: logging, sequelize.js, correlation

My REST API server contains CRUD endpoints for User entity that is persisted into a DB using **Sequelize**. Each endpoint generates a uuid v4 correlation id that is supposed to be present in every log message. I am using pino and child loggers with correlation id provided as binding options so the dev does not have to worry or even be aware of any correlation id nor the requirement to provide it in every log message (the dev just logs using a logger in a particular context (rest endpoint handler)).

*Is there any way to inject correlation id or a child logger into Sequelize to log Sequelize queries with a different correlation id in different contexts (rest endpoint handlers)?*

I do not want to provide a logger fn in every Sequelize model operation (not practical / tedious / error prone).

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
1. rest handler is called // this is the start of the execution context
2. correlation id CID is generated and injected into logger and ???somehow into Sequelize??? // CID is constant from the perspective of the current execution context
3. some business logic // logs every log message with CID without explicitly specifying it
4. await User.findByPK(id) // I do not want to pass CID in here as it should be clear from the execution context
5. a log message is produced containing CID
6. some business logic // logs every log message with CID without explicitly specifying it
7. rest handler finished // end of the execution context
```

Note: By "injected into logger" I mean that a child logger is created with binding options to ensure that logging properties do not get mixed up.

Comment: You can assign a logger to a sequelize instance and that way it will catch all Sequelize queries and errors.

Comment: @Anatoly I've got logging set up and working. The challenge is to log correlation id (in a convenient way) that changes with every request that lands on the server.

Comment: Do you have some king of request context that you call access everywhere across the server code?

Comment: @Anatoly I have a request context but it is accessible just within the REST request handler.

Comment: What about adding a virtual fields into models that would get the current CID from a request context? Afterwards you can get CID from a model instance to log it along with other info?

Comment: @Anatoly that’s an interesting idea! Would it work for Sequelize operations without model instance (eg update with where clause), though?

Comment: I can't say. Please try and find out.

Comment: It won't work @Anatoly as no model would mean no correlation id.

Comment: Yes, it will work only for a certain model instance

Answer (score 0):

You can attach logging function in every sequalize command like:

query:

```js
 const corellationId = req.headers["x-correlation-id"];
 const myData = await myRepository.findOne({
    attributes: ["id", "name"],
    where: { id },
    logging: (message) => logger.log({ message, corellationId }),
  });
```

insert:

```js
const corellationId = req.headers["x-correlation-id"];
await myRepository.create({
    id: uuidv4(),
    ...data,
  }, 
  {
    logging: (message) => logger.log({ message, corellationId }),
  });
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but does not "scale" if you have a team of devs that would have to follow the same approach consistently in time. That is the main challenge I'm trying to solve. Basically, it needs to be solved as a cross-cutting concern.